# joomla 1.6 paypal donate button

Tags: joomla, paypal, togglebutton, joomla1.6, donations

I've just got Joomla 1.6 up and running.

My question is this:

Do we need plug-ins to add a PayPal donate button on Joomla? Can't we just paste the code in the article?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't paste code in to an article without an extension. By default the article text field cleans any code out before inserting it in to the database. You can install an extension that allows code in articles or a Paypal button extension. I am not a fan of allowing users to insert their own code so the plugin or module method would be the better route. There are quite a few 1.6 native Paypal extensions - http://extensions.joomla.org/search?q=paypal

Answer (score 1):

I just went through the process of getting the PayPal button to work on our Joomla site.  With the help of PayPal's technical support, I found that although I had back-end administrative permission, I had to log-in as the Super Administrator to get it to work.

Log-in as the Super Administrator and go through your article manager to edit the article. Once you are in the article, the "toolbar" above the textbox will have a blue "HTML" button on the right end the second row.  When you click that it opens the HTML editor. I then pasted the PayPal code, and clicked "Update". The PayPal button then appeared in the text box and I was able to adjust the alignment as I wanted.